# Where is the "win" button on a window-8?

Tags: windows-8

I'm new to laptops I recently got it. The sad thing is that every time I play a game or something it says " win + space bar or something to broadcast" so I was wondering if I could do it or actually work so I was wondering where the "win" button is?? please help me and answer this question

Comment: google for "win key" or "windows key" and you'll got result right away

Answer (score 5):

The <kbd>Windows</kbd> (or Win) button on the keyboard is the icon of Windows, typically found on the bottom row of the keyboard.

Either like this:
[image]
Or more updated like this:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

The Windows (or Win) button on the keyboard is the icon of Windows, typically found on the bottom row of the keyboard.

Comment: You've copied the other answer. This answer brings no additional value. Please edit your answer and make it more meaningful.